# Extracting all constants from code object in Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.7

I want to extract all the constants used in a function. In **Python 2.7**, I can iterate over the `co_consts` in the `__code__` of the function and extract all the strings. For e.g.,
**Python 2.7**

```
>>> def func():
...:     return 'foo' if True else ('bar',)

>>> print(func.__code__.co_consts)
(None, 'foo', 'bar', ('bar',)) # no need to look into the tuple as 'bar' is available outside it as well.
```

This would give me `'foo'` and `'bar'` as expected. However, in `Python 3.7`, code object contains `'bar'` only inside the tuple.

**Python 3.7**

```
>>> print(func.__code__.co_consts)
(None, True, 'foo', ('bar',))
```

This means I need to look into the tuple in co_consts as well. My confusion is whether there can be more levels of nesting inside the `co_consts`?

Comment: What are you aiming to do in the end? I mean, `('bar',)` is a constant in itself here. If you want all non-container constants (numbers, strings, True, False, None, whatever), you may need to recursively walk the `co_consts` tuple.

Comment: It's not entirely clear how you define the task you're trying to perform, but it's probably impossible. For example, in `def f(): return 1+2`, there is no trace of `1` or `2` in the resulting function object at all. The `co_consts` tuple is just `(None, 3)`.

Comment: @user2357112 Let's say that I just want to extract only string constants used in the function definition.

Comment: @AKX Thanks for pointing it out. It will require to recursively extract all the container constants. For e.g. `def func(): return 'foo' if True else (('bar',),)`.

Comment: There's no trace of `"a"` or `"b"` after `def f(): return "a" + "b"` either. There's super duper no trace of `"a"` after `def f(): return "a"*0` - the `co_consts` tuple is just `(None, '')`.

Comment: @user2357112 My use case doesn't require string constants obtained after some operations in your examples. We can assume if `"a" + "b"` is mentioned in the code then it will suffice to extract `"ab"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just recursively walk the `co_consts` tuple then:

```py
def x():
    return {
        "y": ("bla" + "ble", ("blo", ["blu", "blip"])),
        ("x", "z"): "blup",
        True: False,
        42: "hello" * 10,
        None: 4 + 1j,
    }


def get_consts(func):
    def walk(cell):
        if isinstance(cell, tuple):
            for item in cell:
                yield from walk(item)
        else:
            yield cell

    yield from walk(func.__code__.co_consts)


for const in get_consts(x):
    print(const)
```

prints

```
None
blable
blo
blu
blip
blup
False
hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello
(4+1j)
y
x
z
True
42
None
```

The order of the constants may not be the same as in the original source; they do correspond to the order in the disassembly though:

```
  5           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('blable')
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('blo')
              4 LOAD_CONST               3 ('blu')
              6 LOAD_CONST               4 ('blip')
              8 BUILD_LIST               2
             10 BUILD_TUPLE              2
             12 BUILD_TUPLE              2

  6          14 LOAD_CONST               5 ('blup')

  7          16 LOAD_CONST               6 (False)

  8          18 LOAD_CONST               7 ('hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello')

  9          20 LOAD_CONST               8 ((4+1j))
             22 LOAD_CONST               9 (('y', ('x', 'z'), True, 42, None))
             24 BUILD_CONST_KEY_MAP      5
             26 RETURN_VALUE
```

EDIT: If you need the original strings as they are in the source, you will need to use the `ast` module instead:

```py
import ast
import inspect


class ConstantGatherer(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.consts = []

    def visit_Str(self, node):
        self.consts.append(node.s)

    def visit_Num(self, node):
        self.consts.append(node.n)


cg = ConstantGatherer()
cg.visit(ast.parse(inspect.getsource(x)))
print(cg.consts)
```

outputs

```
['y', 'x', 'z', 42, 'bla', 'ble', 'blo', 'blu', 'blip', 'blup', 'hello', 10, 4, 1j]
```

Comment: Good that you included that a string `"a" + "b"` will be extracted as `"a+b"` only. Thanks to @user2357112 as well for this point. I will mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: @SaimRaza Glad I could help. I added another solution that extracts the original source constants pre-optimization using the `ast` module.

Answer (score 0):

How to get const parameter value `3` from the function `f` in the code below using `inspect`?

```
def l2_norm(x, axis):
  print("l2_norm", x, axis)

f = lambda x: l2_norm(x, axis=3)
```