# Inline constants in format strings

Tags: python

Very close to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55805574/extracting-all-constants-from-code-object-in-python-3) (but not a duplicate IMHO)

```py
In [1]: def foo():
   ...:     A = 'something' + ' ' + 'good'
   ...:     B = 'is'
   ...:     C = f'{B} going on'
   ...:     return A + C
   ...: 

In [2]: foo.__code__.co_consts
Out[2]: (None, 'something good', 'is', ' going on')
```

Can I somehow help python evaluate the formatted string as a constant?

Since the runtime is able to evaluate string concatenation (as evident by evaluating `'something good'`), I'm curious why it isn't able to evaluate the formatted string as `'is going on'`

Comment: Didn't downvote, but to me it is unclear what your expected result is

Comment: @FlyingTeller I edited my post trying to provide a better explanation

Comment: Shouldn't it be `C = f'{B} going on'` then?

Comment: "(as evident by evaluating `'something is good'`)". Nowhere in your code are you evaluating `'something is good'`.

Comment: Not an expert, but it seems to be that generally the compiler doesn't identify "constants" where doing so would require inference across lines of code. e.g. compare `def foo(): a=5; b=6: c=b*2; return a*c` with `def bar(): a=5; c=6*2; return a*c`. The bytecode of `bar` has `12` as a constant, but the bytecode of `foo` does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `co_consts` list of a code object is created at compilation time, while the evaluation of an f-string is performed at runtime, which is why only the constant parts of an f-string is stored as constants, so that at runtime the interpreter can join these constants with the evaluated values of the expressions in the curly brackets.

The reason why `'something' + ' ' + 'good'` is evaluated into `'something good'` before being stored as one constant is the result of compiler optimizations. With a different Python implementation it can easily be stored as three constants instead of one and the evaluation of their concatenation would be deferred to runtime.